# Finding the magnetic field due to a current carrying field at a point within the circumference

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

This is a question me and my friend were wondering about. How can one calculate the magnetic field due to a current carrying loop at a point in the area enclosed by the loop.

For example, at point P as shown in the attached figure.
[image: Current Carrying Loop]

I feel there are just too many variables to arrive at a solution. Even if we consider it for a point at a fixed distance $x$ from the center, then too the distance to the loop changes as we integrate. However, I have a feeling that analogous to the shell theorem for gravitation/electrostatics, the field should be the same at every point within the area but I can't prove it.

Comment: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-02-physics-ii-electricity-and-magnetism-spring-2007/class-activities/ch9sourc_b_field.pdf

Comment: @Rol Are you talking about the field off-axis?

Comment: Yes, see 9.8 appendix 1

Comment: @Rol I have seen that article before posting the question. But I don't know how that expression reduces to the one I want. It would be great if you can tell me about it.

Comment: look at the figure on that page, what you want is $z=0$.